# git merges have many parents an children within one branch. Is it OK?

Tags: git, merge, commit

We started using git a few days ago.

Some developers didn't pull the changes before pushing their commits to the our central repository. Now we have a tree where some commits have two parents and/or two children within a master branch.

I've read some stuff about git and have not found an information if this condition is OK or not.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
*   d8b3992 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge branch 'master' of url_here
|\  
| * 98720cb commit-message
| * 55b1ca7 commit-message
| * 0caca68 commit-message
| * 81e6b1b commit-message
| * 69adb17 commit-message
| * 1fcccfb commit-message
| * 50b847f commit-message
| *   8fa8d04 Merge branch 'master' of uri_here
| |\  
| | *   b2eca99 commit-message
| | |\  
| | | *   2416fa7 commit-message
| | | |\  
| | | | * cecf435 commit-message
| | | | * 7f233d7 commit-message
| | * | | 85a1aab commit-message
| | |/ /  
| * | | 8297802 commit-message
| * | | f144ef9 commit-message
| * | | 4b3eb46 commit-message
| * | | a142b06 commit-message
| |/ /  
* | | bba7871 commit-message
|/ /  
* | f9479c8 commit-message
|/  
* e443dcb commit-message 
* 547c880 commit-message
```

I had to anonymize the texts of commits.

Please tell me if some potential problems are hidden in such a state of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some developers **pull** before **push**. Anyway, git usually don't allow to push if there will be not fast-forward merge.

Anyway, your situation is typical for git.

Every commit which have 2 (or more) children is a branch point.
(*Imagine two developers who start working simultaneously on two different features.*)

And every commit which have 2 (or more) parents is a merge point.

**UPD** Look at others' people repositories https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs/network